# How to remove items from FilteredList?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using JavaFX 8. I try to filter a TableView and I did that, but I have also some other functionalities like modifying and deleting an item from the Table. After the addition of the filtering the modification work properly but the deleting is Unsupported!!
This is what I implement:

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    refreshCategories();

    FilteredList<Product> filteredProducts = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getProductData(), p -> true);

    categoryCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredProducts.setPredicate(product -> {

            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.equals("None"))
                return true;
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if (product.getCategory().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });


    productTable.setItems(filteredProducts);

}
```

And this is the deleting implementation:

```
@FXML
private void handleDelete() {
    int selectedIndex = productTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
        Action responce = Dialogs.create().title("Supprission").masthead("Supprission definitive")
                .message("Êtes-vous sûre de vouloir supprimer ce produit?").actions(Dialog.Actions.OK, Dialog.Actions.CANCEL).showConfirm();
        if (responce == Dialog.Actions.OK) {
            Product product = productTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            dao.removeProductByEntity(product);
            productTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        }
    } else {
        Dialogs.create().title("Pas de selection").masthead("Pas de produit Selectionné").message("S'il vous plait, selectionné un produit dans la liste.")
                .showWarning();
    }
}
```

this is the line that cause the Exception:

```
productTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
```

And finally this is the Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/584634336.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1759)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at dz.bilaldjago.homekode.controller.ProductOverviewController.handleDelete(ProductOverviewController.java:103)
    ... 61 more
```

My main question is: Is it possible that a ReadOnly list accept modification but not deletion!
I hope this is clean and clear to understand.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a late answer, but maybe someone will find it usefull. I've stumbled upon this problem just today. I'm working on an app which is going to be a simple storehouse manager for a small shop. The main part will be a TableView component which can be dynamically updated by adding, removing or filtering items.

In fact, you can't add od remove items to or from the FilteredList as it will throw an UnsupportedOperationException even when for the operation itself you will wrap it with a basic ObservableList. What one can do is to keep separate  ObservableList and FilteredList of TableView items, and if an update is required update only the first one, than wrap it in the FilteredList and only then use it as a source for TableView.setItems() method.

Demonstration code:

```
public class DynamicFilteredList {
  @FXML
  private TableView tableView;
  @FXML
  private TextField searchField;
  private ObservableList tableItems;
  private FilteredList filteredTableItems;

  private void wrapListAndAddFiltering() {
        //Wrap ObservableList into FilteredList
        filteredTableItems = new FilteredList<>(tableItems, p -> true);

        //Add change listener to searchField component to filter the table view
        searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredTableItems.setPredicate(item -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                String query = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    }

    private void add(Item item) {
        tableItems.add(item);
        wrapListAndAddFiltering();
        tableView.setItems(filteredTableItems);
    }

    private void remove(Item item) {
        tableItems.remove(item);
        wrapListAndAddFiltering();
        tableView.setItems(filteredTableItems);
    }


}
```

The major drawback I see in this approach is that, in the case of very large lists, it can be resource (especially memory) consuming and may have negative inpact on the overall performance of the app.

Comment: not sure if at the time  of this answer the FilteredList was already stable enough for using, but: nowadays it's plain wrong to create and set a new filteredList on modifications of the source list, that's the task of the FilteredList itself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i figured out, that you can access the underlying List with

```
myFilteredList.getSource()
```

In my case i was using an ObservableList and was able to remove items from the Source List using

```
myFilteredList.getSource().remove(itemReference);
```

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question even easier. First I declared the following fields:

```
ObservableList<SomeData> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<SomeData> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(observableList);

...
filteredList.setPredicate(t -> !t.isGreen() || showGreenCheckBox.isSelected());
tableView.setItems(filteredList);
```

I perform all operations on the contents of the `tableView` on the `observableList`, for example:

`observableList.remove(someData);`

Or

`observableList.add(someData);`

Comment: yeah true - but you don't need to keep a reference to the source list (you might, particularly if you also use it elsewhere), grabbing the source of the transformation list as outlined in the other question is good enough :)

Comment: @kleopatra, I used `observableList` because in some cases deleting values from the table resulted in `UnsupportedOperationException`. Such a case and its solution are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225349/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-for-removing-a-row-from-the-javafx-table

Comment: probably wasn't clear enough: yes, you need to access the source list for modifications - no, you don't need to keep a reference to the source list, the transform has api to access it.